# babel-preset-env fails to install

Tags: babeljs, event-stream

While installing babel-preset-env,
    npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env

It says 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6
It appears that event-stream was pulled from npm because of a security issue, but it appears that babel-preset-env still relies on it.
Any tips on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed babel-preset-env without problem.

The 3.3.6 version doesn't exists (anymore?) indeed : https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream?activeTab=versions

You might have a packages.json.lock file that force you to this particular version ?